# What does "adverse decisions" mean in this context?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

> Institutionally, consensus democracy has proven its worth in stormy
> weather. Surveys show that consensus democracy gets rising popularity
> and is even more appreciated by ordinary citizens than by the Swiss
> elites (MIS Trend 2008; Credit Suisse 2018). Here, however, we may
> identify the real weak spot of Swiss consensus democracy today.
> Polarisation, stimulated by the political parties of the right and of
> the left, leaves its traces in political culture. Pluralism, positive
> belief in compromise and cooperation, tolerance towards differences,
> and willingness to accept **adverse decisions** are declining among parts
> of the political elite, and parts of the electorate as well.
>
> *- Swiss Democracy by Wolf Linder*

According to [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/adverse) adverse means:
going against something, or causing harm;

But I don't understand What this decisions are adverse to?

Answer (score 1):

The 'adverse decisions' mentioned here are decisions made by a democratic process which might be adverse to certain individuals.

The text is talking about *consensus democracy*. As I understand it, this is where decisions are taken, not by a majority vote (or any other kind of voting system) but by *consensus* - a joint agreement reached by all concerned and one that takes consideration of points raised by all.

What this paragraph is saying is that this kind of democracy makes it easier for individuals to accept 'adverse' decisions - ones which they might not have made themselves autocratically. It seems to be arguing that, in a normal democratic system where votes are taken, an individual or a minority group might 'lose' the vote and not get the outcome they wanted at all; but in a consensus decision they at least have had some influence.